# Issue with Dynamic requests of URL mode using Loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have recored a script in URL mode using Vugen 11.52,The body part of the  custom request is changing from time to time because of the application build.

So how can i handle such dynamic requests to resolve the issues in script development.

Eg:

> Body=coverList=%5B%7B%22_checboxColumn%22%3Afalse%2C%22isColumnChecked%22%3A%22%22%2C%22naics%22%3A%22%22%2C%22comment%22%3A%22%22%2C%22localPolicytypKey%22%3A%22%22%2C%22policyBkngVal%22%3A%22%22%2C%22frontingtypKey%22%3A%22%22%2C%22limitAmt%22%3A%

Answer (score 1):

If I was to present the data to you like this:

```
Body=coverList=
[{"_checboxColumn":false,
"isColumnChecked":"",
"naics":"",
"comment":"",
"localPolicytypKey":"",
"policyBkngVal":"",
"frontingtypKey":"",
"limitAmt":...
```

Would you have a clearer picture of the dynamic data that you would need to address with your own code and the types of string conversions which would be required?

Answer (score 0):

If your are load testing REST calls, please refer to the following link to use web_custom_request to build your dynamic payload.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/Load-testing-of-a-REST-API-using-HP-LoadRunner-s-web-custom/ba-p/6174105

HTH

Comment: While that link may provide an answer to the question, you should include the relevant parts of the solution in your answer. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page is changed or removed.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with REST uniquely.   The payload for the body element is in a specific encoding and is built up from dynamic information passed back from the server.  The user of the tool will need to understand what information is being collected, how to build a string dynamically and then how to convert it to the proper encoding.   This involves tool mechanics, programming skills and once again, tool mechanics.